# Separating Spring-WS and Spring-Webmvc

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Doing a SOAP based application using `spring-ws`. But if i add this following dependency (saw from spring-boot tutorials https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/),

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

It also pulls `spring-webmvc`. If i exclude it,

```
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

I get error here;

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    //ERROR Here
    //cannot find symbol
    //symbol:   method setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext)
    //location: variable servlet of type MessageDispatcherServlet
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
}
```

Arn't they separate modules? Why i must use `spring-webmvc`, when i just need `spring-ws`?

What i don't understand here?

Comment: More details please. (1) Can you show your pom _with_ the exclusion. (2) Can you post the actual error (with stack trace).

Comment: @Tim : It's a compile time error. Shows in IDE. And Updated question.

Comment: In which case the error message you have included is obviously not copied directly. The message would say something more like "No method setApplicationContext on .... " please paste it verbatim.

Comment: @Tim : Ok, updated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spring-ws-core` needs `spring-webmvc`, you can't avoid that as some of the core Spring-WS classes are built on top of Spring-WebMVC classes (including MessageDispatcherServlet).

The `spring-ws-core` POM defines an explicit dependency on `spring-webmvc`

From https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/ws/spring-ws-core/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-ws-core-2.2.4.RELEASE.pom

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.9.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Adding exclusions in maven is *rarely* a good idea - sometimes you need to do it, but you're pretty much saying that you think you understand the libraries dependencies better than the packager did, and you probably don't.

As for the error message, `MessageDispatcherServlet` inherits from `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet`, which is packaged in `spring-webmvc`. The `setApplicationContext` method defined on `FrameworkServlet`, but was only added in the 4.x release of *Spring-WebMVC*.

When you add the exclusion, it looks like the net effect is that you're ending up with an older version of spring-webmvc, from before `setApplicationContext` was added to `FrameworkServlet`.